# Actions must be plain objects while using PUT method

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I try to updated my DB object but all I get is this error `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions`.

Any idea how do I fix this?

```
export function updateUserData(firstName, lastName) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    const state = getState();
    const { user_id, token } = state.auth;
    return axios.put(USER_DATA(user_id), { firstName, lastName }, {
      headers: { authorization: token }
    }).then((response) => {
      dispatch(console.log(response.data));
    }).catch((err) => {
      dispatch(console.log("Couldn't update user data."));
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: The error says it all, are using redux-thunk as a middleware? You need to use it so you can have async actions with redux

Comment: Yes I am using Redux-Thunk as you can see I have tagged in post as well. Also I am using `getState()` which is thunk function. As I said this is the only function that is giving me this error and I try to understand what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dispatch` lines are wrong.  `dispatch(console.log())` is the same as `dispatch(undefined)`, and `undefined` is definitely not a plain action object.